# Sum values based on last 12 months trailing data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample data which has data for more than one year. Based on the data I have to sum the values for last 12 months. In last 12 months the number of rows is not fixed, can be 12, 9, 4 etc. Also 12 months should be taken from the first date that is present for each category and beyond (here it is RIC) COLUMN A.

Sample data:

[image]

So we have to group by RIC,  here are two of them and sum the values from Adjusted for 12 months previous from the first date appearing for that group , so for the category TECL.P the sum should be from 12/22/2020 to 3/24/2020 - should not include the same month from the previous year. Likewise, for CSML it should be from 12/30/2020 to 3/25/2020.

This is my first post so please let me know if anything is required.

```
Adding  data as text :

RIC         DIVIDENDEXDATE       Adjusted 
==============================================
TECL.P      12/22/2020             0
TECL.P      9/22/2020              0
TECL.P      6/23/2020              0
TECL.P      3/24/2020              0.019
TECL.P      12/23/2019             0.111
TECL.P      9/24/2019              0.007
CSML.OQ     12/30/2020             0.146
CSML.OQ     9/24/2020              0.069
CSML.OQ     6/24/2020              0.62
CSML.OQ     3/25/2020              0.018
CSML.OQ     12/30/2019             0.0657
CSML.OQ     9/24/2019              0.6585
```

Comment: can you add your data as text?

Comment: Added data as text

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert your data to a time series and use `rolling` on a window of length 365 days (`'365D'`):

```
df['DIVIDENDEXDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DIVIDENDEXDATE']) + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd()  # ensures that same month a year earlier will not be considered in sum, but assumes your data has a monthly frequency!
df.set_index(['RIC', 'DIVIDENDEXDATE'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(level=['RIC', 'DIVIDENDEXDATE'], inplace=True)
df.groupby(level='RIC').apply(lambda grp: grp.reset_index(level='RIC', drop=True).rolling('365D').sum())
```

Comment: Hi I am getting a syntax error on df.DIVIDENDEXDATE

Comment: @eeco_haldia `df.DIVIDENDEXDATE` is equivalent to `df['DIVIDENDEXDATE']` and simply selects the column named `'DIVIDENDEXDATE'`. In your sample data above it is the second column. Could you please confirm whether your sample data Is correct?

Comment: @eeco_haldia Glad it works. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers